# How to start coding the "Dining Philosophers" simulation?

Tags: c#, deadlock, puzzle

I'm not a beginner at C# but I really need to increase my understanding, so I've picked a classic deadlock problem to code to help teach myself some of the more advanced concepts of C#.  The [Dining Philosophers Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosopher%27s_problem) seems like a good one, but I need a little help to get started.  I know I need to approach the "diners" as objects, but to simulate the random delays between eating, should I look to threading with each diner in a separate thread?  Do I need some kind of "master" to monitor all the actions?  Any general design concept advice is welcome, but I'd like to do the grunt programming as an exercise.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... I'd probably model the "diners" as threads... though they could be objects wrapping threads.

Comment: Jacob, did you ever finish the Dining Philosophers problem?  I am thinking to solve this problem using 2 mutex variables since only 2 philosophers can eat at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best approach to simulate it would be a `Fork` class with a method like `use()` that holds the fork (`bool available = false`) and a `release()` that releases it.

A `Philosopher` class with `getFork(Fork)` and `releaseFork(Fork)` that operates the holding/releasing of the object Fork (seems to me a timer would be good in a method `useFork()` so you can really perceive the deadlock.

And for Last a `DinningTable` (or any other name) class that creates instances, and do the log. If you plan to use threads, here is where you should implement a thread for each `Philosopher` concurring for the `Fork`.

As a suggestion, you could implement a `Plate` Class, holding a quantity of spaghetti that the `Philosopher.useFork()` method lower during the time frame. This way you can see which `Philosopher` finishes first.

I will let the implementations for you, of course, since your objective is to learn C# ... in my experience, you better learn doing something concrete like these classes ;) Besides, you can find lots of implementations on Google if you want to cheat ...

I invite you to share the code after it . It's a great Study Reference.

Hope This helps you.